# Error 1064 with MySQL Workbench, with CREATE TABLE function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, create-table

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to create tables inside a Database,
I used the 'Create a new table' function that appears on my SQL Workbench, instead of manually trying to add them. It writes this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Bory`.`Produits` (
  `idProduits`  NOT NULL,
  `Marque` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `NomProduit` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduits`));
```

So I go and click on "Apply" but I receive this message :

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bory`.`Produits` (
  `idProduits`  NOT NULL,
  `Marque` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `NomProduit` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduits`));
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
> `Marque` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
> `NomProduit` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
> PRIMAR' at line 2

So now I am lost, because why is does function that is native to the Workbench itself keep making mistakes and doesn't let me add tables?

Comment: `idProduits` has no data type

Comment: `idProduits  NOT NULL` , missing data type  change it to `idProduits int  NOT NULL` .https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=689970042b9a67f65d11c3714a94d96e

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in comments, You did't specified the data type for idProduits. for instance use int like below:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Bory`.`Produits` (
  `idProduits` int NOT NULL,
  `Marque` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `NomProduit` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduits`));
```

Comment: Thanks guys!!!! You are the best!! Lol for real though, helping young noobs like myself will get you great karma! see you next time